# How to obtain predicted group means and group slopes from an mblogit object?

Tags: r

With a categorical variable `t` and some covariate `x`, I run the random-effects multinomial logit:

```
model <- mblogit(t ~ x, data = sample, random = ~1 + x|group)
```

How can I then extract predicted group intercepts and group slopes from `model`?

You can find a toy dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1My68wxdRsgTAAGlfqQdd9S5rZ4WRW_Py?usp=sharing) with the necessary variables. The categorical variable `t` must be a factor, so the relevant command is:

```
model <- mblogit(as.factor(t) ~ x, data = toySample, random = ~1 + x|group)
```

Comment: using the `coef` function

Comment: That is what I'm used to from lme4 objects, but mblogit just gives me the fixed coefficients.

Comment: Would you mind providing some (toy) data to reproduce the results?

Comment: @Taufi I have now provided a dataset. Thanks for your time.